# How come my encrypted drives/partitions randomly do not decrypt upon booting?

Tags: arch-linux, encryption, luks, manjaro, disk-encryption

I have the following encrypted.
- HOME drive
- SWAP partition
- BACKUP drive

I use a keyfile on a USB stick to decrypt my drives upon booting.

Sometimes, and I mean RANDOMLY, upon booting up my system, it decides not to decrypt some or even all of my encrypted drives/partitions. It's a real pain in the butt because it sort of causes a chain reaction to happen and when I press Ctrl + Alt + Del to reboot again it just happens again. It's not until the 3rd or 5th time that it ends up working again.

Why does this randomly happen sometimes and how can I fix it?

Below is just some of my system info:

```
$ inxi -Fx
System:
  Host: x-pc Kernel: 4.19.28-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.2.1 
  Desktop: Xfce 4.13.2git-UNKNOWN Distro: Manjaro Linux 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Micro-Star product: MS-7B09 v: 1.0 serial: <root required> 
  Mobo: Micro-Star model: X399 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B09) v: 1.0 
  serial: <root required> UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: 1.70 date: 12/18/2017 
Battery:
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 2S 
  charge: 100% (should be ignored) status: Discharging 
  Device-2: hidpp_battery_1 model: Logitech K800 charge: 70% (should be ignored) 
  status: Full 
CPU:
  Topology: 16-Core (2-Die) model: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X bits: 64 
  type: MT MCP MCM arch: Zen rev: 1 L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 217693 
  Speed: 3584 MHz min/max: 2200/3400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3699 2: 3597 3: 3256 
  4: 3137 5: 3338 6: 3143 7: 3324 8: 3129 9: 3730 10: 3703 11: 3297 12: 3692 13: 3551 
  14: 3144 15: 3268 16: 3556 17: 3149 18: 3208 19: 3782 20: 3690 21: 3691 22: 3694 
  23: 3695 24: 3646 25: 3691 26: 3694 27: 3526 28: 3521 29: 3185 30: 3495 31: 3734 
  32: 3798 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] vendor: eVga.com. driver: nvidia 
  v: 418.43 bus ID: 42:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: nvidia resolution: 3440x1440~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.43 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 0c:00.3 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP102 HDMI Audio vendor: eVga.com. driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 42:00.1 
  Device-3: Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
  bus ID: 9-3:2 
  Device-4: C-Media type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus ID: 9-4:3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.19.28-1-MANJARO 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: igb v: 5.4.0-k 
  port: 7000 bus ID: 08:00.0 
  IF: enp8s0 state: down mac: 30:9c:23:28:63:36 
  Device-2: Broadcom and subsidiaries vendor: ASUSTeK driver: brcmfmac v: kernel 
  port: 7000 bus ID: 0a:00.0 
  IF: asus_wifi state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: 34:97:f6:b6:a7:e8 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 17.56 TiB used: 3.17 TiB (18.1%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 960 PRO 1TB size: 953.87 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: SanDisk model: SD8SB8U1T001122 size: 953.87 GiB 
  ID-3: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST2000LM015-2E8174 size: 1.82 TiB 
  ID-4: /dev/sdc type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Cruzer Fit size: 7.45 GiB 
  ID-5: /dev/sdd type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Gaming Xbox 360 size: 14.91 GiB 
  ID-6: /dev/sde vendor: Western Digital model: WD6002FFWX-68TZ4N0 size: 5.46 TiB 
  ID-7: /dev/sdf vendor: Western Digital model: WD20EADS-11R6B1 size: 1.82 TiB 
  ID-8: /dev/sdg vendor: Seagate model: ST5000LM000-2AN170 size: 4.55 TiB 
  ID-9: /dev/sdh type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Ultra Fit size: 57.28 GiB 
  ID-10: /dev/sdi vendor: Western Digital model: WD1003FZEX-00MK2A0 size: 931.51 GiB 
  ID-11: /dev/sdj vendor: Crucial model: CT1050MX300SSD4 size: 978.09 GiB 
  ID-12: /dev/sdk type: USB model: Memorex USB Flash Drive size: 115.32 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 97.93 GiB used: 15.37 GiB (15.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
  ID-2: /boot size: 9.99 GiB used: 95.6 MiB (0.9%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
  ID-3: /home size: 961.73 GiB used: 122.80 GiB (12.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-2 
  ID-4: swap-1 size: 128.00 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-0 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 48.4 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 58 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 34% 
Info:
  Processes: 535 Uptime: 1h 01m Memory: 125.79 GiB used: 5.89 GiB (4.7%) Init: systemd 
  Compilers: gcc: 8.2.1 Shell: bash v: 5.0.0 inxi: 3.0.32






$ lsblk -a
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0 953.9G  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    0  93.1G  0 part  
├─sda2          8:2    0  23.3G  0 part  /mnt/UBUNTU_ROOT
├─sda3          8:3    0  23.3G  0 part  /mnt/UBUNTU_HOME
├─sda4          8:4    0  23.3G  0 part  /mnt/DISTRO_ROOT
└─sda5          8:5    0  23.3G  0 part  /mnt/DISTRO_HOME
sdb             8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─sdb1          8:17   0   1.8T  0 part  /mnt/SB_2TB_HDD
sdc             8:32   1   7.5G  0 disk  
└─sdc1          8:33   1   7.5G  0 part  /mnt/SYS_UTIL
sdd             8:48   1  14.9G  0 disk  
├─sdd1          8:49   1   1.9G  0 part  /mnt/M1803
└─sdd2          8:50   1     4M  0 part  
sde             8:64   0   5.5T  0 disk  
└─sde1          8:65   0   5.5T  0 part  /mnt/WD_6TB_HDD
sdf             8:80   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─sdf1          8:81   0   1.8T  0 part  /mnt/WD_2TB_HDD
sdg             8:96   0   4.6T  0 disk  
└─SB_5TB_HDD  254:1    0   4.6T  0 crypt /mnt/SB_5TB_HDD
sdh             8:112  1  57.3G  0 disk  
└─sdh1          8:113  1  57.3G  0 part  /mnt/LIVE_CDS
sdi             8:128  0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdi1          8:129  0   4.7G  0 part  /mnt/WIN_SETUP
├─sdi2          8:130  0 465.7G  0 part  /mnt/WIN_FILESYS
└─sdi3          8:131  0 461.1G  0 part  /mnt/WIN_SHARED
sdj             8:144  0 978.1G  0 disk  
└─sdj1          8:145  0 978.1G  0 part  
  └─MJRO_HOME 254:2    0 978.1G  0 crypt /home
sdk             8:160  1 115.3G  0 disk  
└─sdk1          8:161  1 115.3G  0 part  /mnt/MX_128GB_USB (LUKS KEYFILE)
sr0            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
nvme0n1       259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0    10G  0 part  /boot
├─nvme0n1p2   259:2    0   100G  0 part  /
└─nvme0n1p3   259:3    0   128G  0 part  
  └─MJRO_SWAP 254:0    0   128G  0 crypt [SWAP]






$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
algif_skcipher         16384  0
af_alg                 28672  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               40960  3
dm_mod                155648  7 dm_crypt
nls_iso8859_1          16384  3
nls_cp437              20480  3
vfat                   24576  3
fat                    81920  1 vfat
isofs                  45056  1
fuse                  118784  9
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     57344  1
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
edac_mce_amd           28672  0
kvm_amd               106496  0
joydev                 24576  0
kvm                   737280  1 kvm_amd
input_leds             16384  0
mousedev               24576  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  1
uvcvideo              118784  1
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    86016  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
cdc_acm                32768  0
nvidia_drm             53248  4
videobuf2_common       53248  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
nvidia_modeset       1089536  6 nvidia_drm
pcbc                   16384  0
brcmfmac              389120  0
snd_usb_audio         258048  2
snd_hda_intel          45056  3
videodev              217088  4 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
drm_kms_helper        208896  1 nvidia_drm
media                  45056  2 videodev,uvcvideo
snd_usbmidi_lib        32768  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
aesni_intel           200704  7
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_rawmidi
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
snd_hda_codec         151552  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
drm                   495616  7 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 28672  6 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
snd_hda_core           94208  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
cfg80211              778240  1 brcmfmac
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
agpgart                49152  1 drm
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_pcm               131072  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
pcspkr                 16384  0
igb                   249856  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_timer              36864  1 snd_pcm
snd                    98304  22 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
sp5100_tco             16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 igb
dca                    16384  1 igb
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
i2c_piix4              24576  0
mmc_core              176128  1 brcmfmac
k10temp                16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ccp                    98304  1 kvm_amd
rng_core               16384  1 ccp
rfkill                 28672  3 cfg80211
wmi                    28672  2 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi
evdev                  28672  12
pinctrl_amd            28672  0
gpio_amdpt             16384  0
pcc_cpufreq            16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_cpufreq           24576  0
nvidia              17629184  245 nvidia_modeset
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler        65536  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
crypto_user            16384  0
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               45056  1 ip_tables
ext4                  737280  11
crc32c_generic         16384  0
crc16                  16384  1 ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  126976  1 ext4
fscrypto               32768  1 ext4
sr_mod                 28672  0
cdrom                  69632  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 61440  26
hid_logitech_hidpp     40960  0
hid_logitech_dj        24576  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   139264  4 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            73728  5 uas
ahci                   40960  12
libahci                40960  1 ahci
crc32c_intel           24576  22
libata                278528  2 libahci,ahci
xhci_pci               16384  0
scsi_mod              253952  5 sd_mod,usb_storage,uas,libata,sr_mod
xhci_hcd              266240  1 xhci_pci
```

Comment: Any specific errors when things don't go right? Using UUIDs, not sdX names?

Comment: To troubleshoot such a problem what we need are logs. Logs which show what is happening at that moment in the boot process. Have you considered using a different USB drive? Perhaps the one you're using is not reliable enough.

Comment: Of course! Logs! Sorry about that! What is the log command you'd like to see the output of? I'll run it right after it happens and post the output here. Yes, I have tried several different USB drives, even an expensive Samsung one did the same thing at random times just like it's doing now.